# Is it possible to rename linux network namespaces

Tags: linux, networking

Is it possible to rename a linux network namespace. I am using ubuntu server 14. I just created a network namespace and configured it, but would like to rename it.

Comment: Looks like maybe the answer is no.  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html    http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Namespaces themselves have no name; `ip` just attaches one by mounting the namespace fd on top of a blank file. So you could do this:

```
touch /run/netns/NewName
mount --move /run/netns/OldName /run/netns/NewName
rm /run/netns/OldName
```

In case `mount --move` does not work, the following should:

```
touch /run/netns/NewName
mount --bind /run/netns/OldName /run/netns/NewName
umount /run/netns/OldName
rm /run/netns/OldName
```

Comment: If you are rebinding the old netns to the newns, you will not be able to rm it until you are done with the newly-nmed netns.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Only if you forget to umount the old namespace, no?

Comment: Nope, I just tried it, and it did not work. I was curious because it's a trick I did not know.

Comment: Hm, well, it certainly works here – as soon as `findmnt` no longer shows the old namespace as mounted, it is removable with both `rm` and `ip netns rm`.

Comment: No, it does **not** work here. rm'ing the old netns prompts a *device busy* reply: a lazy unmount + rm leaves me unable to access the new netns. *Linux hague 3.16.0-40-generic #54~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 10 17:30:45 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux* Kubuntu  fully updated. I wonder what the difference is: perhaps the fact that when I try to do this I already have several NICs and openvpns open, *i.e.* a fully operational netns?